# Enlarging initials field in AD

Tags: active-directory

I have two 2008R2 domain controllers in one domain.

The user attribute "initials" can only contain 6 chars. I need it to be 12.
What is the impact of using adsiedit to enlarge this attribute to more than 6 chars?

Do I have to do this on every DC, or will the schema edit be automatically replicated?

Comment: Are you trying to shoehorn something else into initials?

Comment: @TomO'Connor, Yes. Dutch names have "tussenvoegsels" between the given name and surname. There is no field in AD for that. I want to use the initials field since Exchange 2010 can use it in E-mail address policies.

Comment: Oh, you mean like X van der Y?

Comment: @TomO'Connor, yep! But it's working now. I just needed some patience and wait for AD to replicate the schema change to the DC the Exchange server was communicating with. Works fine now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q: The user attribute "initials" can only contain 6 chars. I need it to be 12. What is the impact of using adsiedit to enlarge this attribute to more than 6 chars?

A: Initials will have a rangeUpper attribute value of 12 rather than 6. Other than that I don't see any "impact".

Q: Do I have to do this on every DC, or will the schema edit be automatically replicated?

A: There is only one Schema parition in the forest and all DC's in the forest hold a copy of it. Any changes to the Schema partition will be replicated to all DC's in the forest.

Comment: Just enlarged the field. I needed it to be larger for the Exchange E-mail address policies, but now Exchange gives an error when trying to create the mailbox stating "Error:
The length of the property is too long. The maximum length is 6 and the length of the value provided is 7.". How to ignore this length error?